# Displaying my content without HTML tags

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I am trying to display something on my website from my database but it will return it with HTML tags. In this case down here it will return it with `strong` tags but their are also others with a `<i>` and `<em>` like this one down here

```
T<u>his is my </u>texta<em>rea to be replaced with C</em>KEditor.
```

Example:

```
var_dump($help = $reactie['reactie']);
var_dump(strip_tags($help , "<strong><b><i><bold>"));
```

When I var_dump those it will return this:

```
string(78) "<strong>This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.</strong>"
string(78) "<strong>This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.</strong>"
```

What I want is that it will return only the text and not the `<strong>`

This also doesn't work:

```
 var_dump($help = $reactie['reactie']);
 var_dump(strip_tags($help));
```

This will stil return the same thing.

My code:

```
                $fotoreactie = $app->reactiefoto($reactie['id']);
                foreach ($fotoreactie as $reactiefoto) {

                    if(file_exists("assets/images/reactiefotos/thumbs/".$reactiefoto['foto']) && !empty($reactiefoto['foto'])){ 
                    echo '<a href="/assets/images/reactiefotos/'.$reactiefoto['foto']. '" data-fancybox><img src="/assets/images/reactiefotos/thumbs/'.$reactiefoto['foto']. '" /> </a>';
                    }
                }
                var_dump($help = $reactie['reactie']);
                var_dump(strip_tags($reactie['reactie']));
                echo '
                    <form name="formName" style="margin-top:5px;">
                       <input type=hidden id="'.$reactie['id'].'" name="abcName" value="'.$reactie['id'] .'"/>
                       <input type=hidden id="naam'.$reactie['id'].'"name="abcName" value="Reactie op bericht van '.$reactie['voornaam'].' ' .$reactie['achternaam'].'"/>
                       <input type=hidden id="naam2'.$reactie['id'].'"name="abcName" value="'. $help .'"/>
                       <a href="#reactie"><input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type=button value="Reageer" onclick="printIt(\''.$reactie['id'] .'\')" /></a>

                    </form>';
                ?>`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: By passing `"<strong><b><i><bold>"` to the `strip_tags()` function you are telling it to allow those tags.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Why are you saving the HTML tags to your database, if you don't intend to use them? Better to properly sanitise the string before inserting it than doing it on the output.

Comment: @Matadeleo I am using CKEditor and it will post it in the DB that way. And I use those HTML tags on other thing on my website

Comment: where are you checking your output? is it in browser? then there may be html entities displayed as tags.

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags()` will do this for you:

```
$x = 'T<u>his is my </u>texta<em>rea to be <strong>replaced</strong> with C</em>KEditor.';
echo strip_tags($x);
```

Which outputs:

```
This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
```

Which you can see for yourself here https://3v4l.org/ksQS5

Comment: `var_dump($help = $reactie['reactie']);` and 
    `var_dump(strip_tags($help));` will still give me back the same thing as I mantioned

Comment: if you look at my example you can see i added strong tags too just to show you

Comment: well as you can see in my question what also didn't work it still isn't working for me.

Comment: well then there must be additional code you aren't telling us about? Can you reproduce your issue on https://3v4l.org ?

Comment: That is not really possible. I am using functions in my code and a `foreach` loop. Can it be that the problem is that it is in a `foreach` loop/

Comment: Posted it in the question

Comment: Here's your problem `<input type=hidden id="naam2'.$reactie['id'].'"name="abcName" value="'. $help .'"/>`

Comment: $help is never stripped of tags based on youir posted code

Comment: well even If I do this: `value="'. strip_tags($help) .'"/>` it won't work